# Is there no longer a connect URL for using the Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook

Its quite possible I'm missing something obvious here; I hope so.

I have been trying to get a Facebook game that posts to the user's wall after the game has finished working. As I understand it, this should be a pretty simple process (and there appears to be several different approaches).

I have tried most of these, and they all seem to fail for the same reason; I do not have a 'connect' URL (which, as I understand it, is also called a canvas callback URL?) set correctly.

This sounds easy to fix, but it seems like the application settings page has recently changed. Often a 'connect' tab is referred to, but this no longer exists. All I have is a 'Facebook integration' tab and this has only the canvas URL, there doesn't appear to be a connect URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the URL in the Website Section. You'd be best settings the domain as well just to make sure. I find it best practise to set the URL in the Facebook Integration tab as well as then Website tab regardless of the type of Facebook integration I am creating

You are correct that the error message is out of date, the connect URL is the Website URL now (just wanted to clarify)

Comment: Oh wow... I don't know how I missed it. Haven't tried it yet, but that'll be the problem I'm sure. Thanks!